# Setting start date parameter to display in SSRS report as Day1

Tags: datetime, matrix, reporting-services, summary

Is there a way to set the Start Date parameter to 1, next day would be 2, next day would be 3.
I would like to group on this and do day/week/month/year summaries.

I want to change the report that is attached to be a matrix report displaying days instead of dates starting with day 1 for whatever day is chosen.  To go across the columns in a matrix and then aggregate those calculations to week/month/year summaries

[Current Report by Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXx9v.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I used the DAY function in SSRS.  DAY(Fields!created_date.Value)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).